# Resstrict anonymouse user to access the site

Tags: piranha-cms

We are building a website inwhich user must be authenticated before access the site. However, I don't know if it's possible to do that in Piranha?
I used

```
      <authorization>
          <deny users ="?"/>
      </authorization>
```

but it does not work.

Is anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Piranha CMS uses forms authentication, so the above should work if you add a login url to the forms configuration in the web.config. I have used that setup myself for a couple of projects.

If you want to set restrictions on page level you can do this under **Settings** for a page, where you can choose the group needed to view the page.

If you're using MVC you can also add the `[Authorize]` attribute to your controllers/actions as usuall. Basically the normal steps should apply!

Regards